# Order by Sum Field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I try to write a SQL-Statement in X++. It should do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Table.field1, SUM(Table.field2) AS SumField
FROM 
    Table
WHERE 
    Table.FieldX = Something
GROUP BY 
    Table.Field1
ORDER BY 
    SumField;
```

The problem i have in X++ is that it orders the records before calculating the sum of them. I know that i could make a `While Select` in X++ and order them by code, but that is not the way i want to do it.

Can someone tell me how i could handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot both do a `sort by` and `group by` in a X++ select or query.

The solution is to make a view (without the sort), then do a select on the view with the order by.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, I think this should work for me!